# How to get number of likes and comments of a page's posts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

Facebook is deprecating "page_like_adds" and "page_comments_adds". They were useful to know how many likes and/or comments have been posted on the page content.

Now, with the new "page_stories_by_story_type", at best, you get the number of "stories" generated by your content (it includes likes, comments and shares), but you have no figures for each one.

Do you know any other way to get likes and comments counts on page ?

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you happen to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I may have this wrong but I think you just need to get the object in the Graph via the graph API.

For example

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

```
{
"id": "40796308305",
"name": "Coca-Cola",
"picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276879_40796308305_1578420141_s.jpg",
"link": "http://www.facebook.com/coca-cola",
"likes": 36470992,
"category": "Food/beverages",
"website": "http://www.coca-cola.com",
"username": "coca-cola",
"founded": "1886",
"description": "On May 8, 2011, Coca-Cola marks its 125th anniversary. Created in 1886 in Atlanta, Georgia, by Dr. John S. Pemberton, Coca-Cola was first offered as a fountain beverage at Jacob's Pharmacy by mixing Coca-Cola syrup with carbonated water. \n\nCoca-Cola was patented in 1887, registered as a trademark in 1893 and by 1895 it was being sold in every state and territory in the United States. In 1899, The Coca-Cola Company began franchised bottling operations in the United States. \n\nCoca-Cola might owe its origins to the United States, but its popularity has made it truly universal. Today, you can find Coca-Cola in virtually every part of the world.",
"can_post": true,
"checkins": 77,
"talking_about_count": 193996
}
```

Notice the "likes", "checkin" and "talink_about_count"? Do these properties of the page object not give you what you want? If you want the "likes" and other properties for individual posts on a page you have the choice of using FQL or going to the "posts" connection and looking at the likes/comments for each. The latter however may take a long time to process but I don't know the wider scope of the project or its aims so this is all pretty general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Graham. The details of the page doesn't give the details in the number of likes and comments on posts unfortunately. Obviously, you can use the page's stream to measure the number of likes and comments for the posts of a certain date range. But if fans like and comment on older posts, you won't count them. I really don't understand why they're deprecating these key metrics.

Answer (score 0):

```
#this might help you

import facebook
token='add token here'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
#to get the page data
page = graph.get_object('6127898346')
#to get the post of the page add the post id 
page_post=graph.get_object('10155272237029571')
print(page_post)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.